# Mongo Db Time format

Tags: mongodb

I want to save the time in mongoDB inorder to add the teacher availability in a school.how can i store time of day in mongodb as a string.
(I want to store like 03:30 PM)
Please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Why not just store as the numeric milliseconds from the start of the day? It takes less space than a string and has a lot more general uses.

Answer (score 3):

you can user mongoose user schema's pre function which trigger every time you added anything using the schema. inside that use conditional function how you want to save the specific schema model . i have done your  time model . let me know if you have any confusion.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
time: String
});


UserSchema.pre('save',
function (next) {
    if (!this.time) {
        var newdate = new Date();
        var Fulllocaltime =  newdate.toLocaleString('en-US');
        var array = Fulllocaltime.split(" ");
        var finaloutput = array[1]+' '+array[2];

        this.time =finaloutput;
    }
    next();
}
);
```